# Getting rails version on production with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

So I have a rails app that is up and running with puma and RVM. All I want is to know what rails version it is running. `ruby -v` works, but `rails -v` doesn't.

Here's my output:

```
deploy@foo:/data/apps/foo.staging/current$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]

deploy@foo:/data/apps/foo.staging/current$ rails -v
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

deploy@foo:/data/apps/foo.staging/current$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]

#  => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

deploy@foo:/data/apps/foo.staging/current$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p353 (found in /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353)
   (default)
   global
```

Comment: Probably you have installed Rails in another gemset. You can change it with `rvm gemset use global`.

Comment: Look in Gemfile.lock???

Comment: @WizardofOgz So he could get the version of course, but this wasn't the question He asked why `rails -v` is not working.

Comment: @Robin: The production is already using a gemset (not listed above). That is the version I would like to know of. And I actually just want to know the version, although would be nice to know why `rails -v` isn't working.

Comment: @dan-klasson: I see, but is rails installed to this gemset you are using, when you are running `rails -v`.

Comment: @WizardofOgz: Yes, there it is. `rails (3.2.22)`. Cool, thanks. Post as answer and I will accept.

Comment: @Robin: I assume so yes, otherwise I would not be able to run the code successfully with puma against that directory? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @dan-klasson awesome! I didn't know if you needed something else besides that. Answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in `Gemfile.lock` to see which version of Rails your app is using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bundler, you can run:

```
bundle exec rails -v
```